# How to integrate expert knowledge to outlier detection algorithms?

Tags: outliers, domain-adaptation

Suppose I have a dataset of `20` features, `X1`, `X2`..`X20`.

Say I perform an outlier detection algorithm such as One-class SVM (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html) or IsolationForest (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) on the dataset.

Suppose that I have some domain knowledge, such as if `X1<10` the data point is really `abnormal`, or if `X2==1` the value of `X4` is not important anymore etc.

How could I integrate these information to One-class SVM or IsolationForest?

Comment: As an independent check of the validity of the outlier detection rule?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: You have two outlier detection algorithm that you see fit to use. Clearly they will not give you the same list of outliers. Which algorithm should you use? Maybe the one that overlaps the most with the expert's list. At list you will have the experts on your side!

Comment: But the expert knowledge is not complete - it is kind of ``guidance`` rather than a complete set of rules.

Comment: sure, as long as the expert guidance are is not *wrong* this strategy will help.